# how to create a menu bar in Access 2007 Form using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need to create a custom menu bar in Access 2007 Form using VBA

For example

```
Maintenance      Reports
   Employee         Employee Report  
   Attendance       Attendance Report
```

How to achieve this using VBA in Access 2007 Form?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will find this useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa338202(office.12).aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers_Access

Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa338199(office.12).aspx

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jensenh/archive/2006/05/25/606819.aspx